# C hashtable Set/Get void* unique memory address

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

Hashtable uses linked lists at each entry in the table.  Hashcode algorithm generates an index.  The input to the hashcode algorithm is the key from the key/value pair.  The hashcode algorithm takes a char* input and outputs an integer index. Hashtable Get/Set methods can take input of any type by using void* and the size of the data.  In order to generate an almost unique index the input string must be unique but the Set/Get functions need to correspond with each other so that if the key is "foobar" in the Set function then the later call to Get using "foobar" maps to the same hashtable index.

The problem is the input is void* and a unique string is needed to generate an index then the only thing I can think of using is a string representation of the unique memory address of the key in the node in the link list that will be stored at that index in the hashtable.

Set Function (partial example code)

```
struct Node* node_to_set = Node_Create(entry->key, entry->data, entry->keysize, entry->datasize);
void* key = Node_Get_Key(node_to_set);
char string_key[256] = {'\0'};
int bytes = sprintf(string_key, "%p", key);
int index = Hashtable_HashCode(hashtable->size, string_key);
```

Get Function (that unique string is lost to the outside caller)

```
//do not know what the memory address is because its in the table
//searching for it would defeat the purpose of a constant time lookup
```

Are there any other ways to do this using void* ?

Comment: I read this at least three times, and have to admit I'm lost as to what the problem *is*. It sounds like you're using a hash table with linked-lists for collision chains. Once you obtain the hash index for a given key, you need to walk the collision chain to find if the entry is present, and depending on the action (set/get) add, update, or fetch, respectively. Equivalence testing *must* be part of the key algorithm. Regardless, don't really follow your question, though it's late so it's possibly just me.

Comment: There are a number of differing hash table implementations and your example code could lend itself to more than one. Generally, a linked-list only comes into play if there is a collision at the index. Then the key at the index is replaced with the first node in a list to resolve collisions in that bucket. Now your general question about *nul-terminating* a unique memory address is separate. If you have keys stored in unique locations, then a hex representation of the address would only contain characters that could be represented as characters in a string. So I don't see why you couldn't try.

Comment: @WhozCraig no, it's not too late and not just you, I read it over again and came to your same conclusion. `:)`

Comment: The problem is that I need a string for void* input.

Comment: If I use an memory address string representation from the outside there us no guarantee it will be unique because it could be freed and reused.  If I use an address representation on the inside then Get call has no reference to it unless it is searched.

Comment: I'm confused by the question too.  However, you should be hashing the data content of the key, both in set and get mode.  That key might well be described by a `void *` to the start of the memory holding the key data and by the length of the key.  Your hash (hash code) algorithm should be using that data (and not the value of the `void *`) to generate the hash code, and then using that to identify the hash table entry list that's relevant, and checking through the list. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  For example, you might generate a 32-bit number from the key; you might then take that value modulo the size of the hash table to identify a list in the hash table.  You'd then check each entry in the list to see whether the recorded 32-bit hash code matches the generated one.  You assume that the keys are identical if the hashes match (and there's a small chance that you're wrong; that's a risk with any hashing algorithm).

Comment: "*Are there any other ways to do this using void\**" <- do *what* using void? You're reading a string from your data, that's a bad idea if you don't know the type. Write your hashing function so it accepts `void *`  and `size_t` itself, alias with a `char *` inside and iterate over **all** bytes (not using `string.h` functions because they would stop at `\0`) to compute your hash value. If this wasn't your question, please try to write a better question, I'm really unsure what exactly your question **is**.

Comment: here's an example [hash function](https://github.com/Zirias/pocas/blob/master/src/lib/core/hashtable.c#L56) working on this definition of a [hash key](https://github.com/Zirias/pocas/blob/master/src/lib/core/hashtable.c#L10).

Comment: Thanks yea my hash function takes an unsigned char* so it casts void* to unsigned char* which means I can use the contents of the key instead of the memory addresss.  The contents of the key is unique by design so it works.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a string representation of a memory address to pass to the hash function.  I used the dereferenced value which is unique because its a key.  I dereferenced it by casting the void* into an unsigned char* and then passed it to the hash function.

```
int index = Hashtable_HashCode(hashtable->size, (unsigned char*)entry->key);

unsigned long Hashtable_HashCode(unsigned int size, unsigned char *str) {
        if(str != NULL) {
                unsigned long hash = 5381;
                unsigned int c = 0;
                while(c = *str++) {
                        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
                }
                hash = hash % size;
                hash = (hash < 0) ? hash * -1 : hash;
                return hash;
        }
        return -1;
}
```